# relational parse query returning false response

Tags: javascript, relational, parse-platform

I have a [parse.js](https://www.parse.com/) query that returns all the rows from a table (tableA), which as expected works; but I only want rows returned that contain a pointer to a row in another table (tableB), in which one field ('Amount') is greater than a specified number. The query is laid out as follows:

```
var tableA = Parse.Object.extend('tableA');
var minSalary = 200;
var q = new Parse.Query(tableA);
q.include('tableB');
q.greaterThan('Amount',minSalary);
```

The result I get back is '0' if I include the last line. I've tried everything including dot notation: `q.include('tableB.Amount')`, and there are several rows in tableA that should have been retrieved.

Why is this?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without some more context:  what library are you using?  Where did this code come from?

Comment: I'm using Parse.js v1.1.14 and this code just comes from my main js file where I need to populate a table.

Comment: Can you add a link to Parse.js's website into the question?

Answer (score 0):

The last line, greaterThan, is being applied to 'tableA'. It sounds like you want to apply this to objects from tableB. You want to use a innerQuery here instead.

```
var tableA = Parse.Object.extend("tableA");
var tableB = Parse.Object.extend("tableB");

var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(tableB);
innerQuery.greaterThan("Amount", salary);

var query = new Parse.Query(tableA);
query.include("tableB");
query.matchesQuery("tableB", innerQuery);
```